# http.FileServer only serves index.html

Tags: http, go, mux

My code for a simple file server:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    // default file handler
    r.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("web")))

    // run on port 8080
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handlers.LoggingHandler(os.Stdout, r)); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

My directory structure is:

```
cmd/server/main.go
web/index.html
web/favicon.ico
web/favicon.png
web/css/main.css
```

`index.html` asks for `main.css`. so when I run `go run cmd/server/main.go` I get the following output:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Dec/2019:22:45:26 -0X00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Dec/2019:22:45:26 -0X00] "GET /css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 19
```

I'm able to see the `index.html` page, but without the CSS. When I request any other file (e.g. `favicon.ico`) I also get a 404. Why does my `FileServer` only serve `index.html`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To demonstrate why this does not work consider the following test app:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type testHandler struct{}

func (h *testHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("Got request for %s\n", r.URL)
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    hndlr := testHandler{}
    r.Handle("/", &hndlr)

    // run on port 8080
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

If you run this and access `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` in your browser it will log `Got request for /`. However if you access  `http://127.0.0.1:8080/foo` you will get a 404 error and nothing will be logged. This is because `r.Handle("/", &hndlr)` will only match on `/` and not anything below it.

If you change this to `r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(&hndlr)` then it will work as you expect (the router will pass all paths to the handler). So to fix your example change `r.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("web")))` to `r.PathPrefix("/").Handler( http.FileServer(http.Dir("web")))`.

Note: Because this is passing all paths to `FileServer` there is really no need to use Gorilla Mux; I have left this in on the assumption that you will be using it to add some other routes.